# Are you allowed to ask questions related to estimates?

Tags: discussion

For example, how long does it take to install / configure Apache Solr as the search engine for a Magento CE build?

Perhaps a related question (or a part of that question) would be to break the task down into the different sub-tasks involved.

UPDATE:

I wanted to reply in comments but had too much to say, so here are some responses to some of the great feedback I've received thus far.

**Precedent in other SE sites**
It looks like cost estimates are [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109596/193112) on Stackoverflow, but are allowed on Programmers.  They talk mostly about the reasons for not asking about costs, but they don't mention things related to time estimates specifically.  Also, part of the reason I thought to ask this on this site is I get the sense this will be a more business-friendly site than others given the nature of the Magento community.  Not sure what that means exactly, but trying to feel that out.

**Depends on experience**

While it's true that any answers related to experience do depend highly upon an individual's experience level, that's not necessarily a problem.  It's actually very useful for me to know that it's possible for Solr to be deployed in one minute for a highly experienced and specialized individual.  It doesn't mean that I would use that estimate myself, but it's useful information none the less.

You might say that multiple people could submit completely different valid answers - one person says it would take a week and another says it would take a minute.  Well for starters, that information alone would probably tell you that the person who says it would take a week is significantly less experienced (and perhaps trustworthy on this particular topic) than the other - which could, again, be useful information.

But also, there are many questions that don't always have One Single Correct Answer to them, such as [What is the Best Magento Server Setup?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/460/what-is-the-best-magento-server-setup).

**Estimates tend to lead to good questions**

I find that the process of thinking through an estimate can lead to a lot of good questions, such as the ones that you posted related to Solr installation - sometimes even more so than if someone simply asks a more generic How-To question.

**Shopping Questions**

I can see the concern with someone just irresponsibly posting a question up for an estimate and giving that to their client without any further due dilligence or thought.  Of course that would be irresponsible, but ultimately it's not our problem to ensure that users are responsible.

I also saw your other question ([Should those profiting from answers be allowed to ask questions?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/should-those-profiting-from-answers-be-allowed-to-ask-questions)) which seems somewhat related.  It seems to me that the vast majority of questions on any SE site will be directly or indirectly related to profit and I actually think that's a Good Thing.

You also say that it could promote people carrying out work that they aren't capable of completing.  Aren't all users asking questions attempting to get help with carrying out work that they are not currently capable of completing?

And, in fact, this could be a safeguard to end clients, because if irresponsible developers are getting their estimates from reliable, trusted sources on this site (reliable, trusted sources are what SE sites tend to produce and highlight), then it should decrease the chances that they would unrealistically bloat estimates.

Answer (score 8):

In order to answer questions related to estimates "how long does it take to...?" detailed information should be provided, also depends on various factors (developer skills, experience, evironment, tools used, etc).

A reformulated question:

> What are the steps [and what skills should someone have] to do a certain
>   task

I believe can be more appropriate and a better answer can be posted.

Comment: I agree that they should be allowed, but with adequate information on the requirements. It's one of those timeless questions, "How long does it take to do something you've never done before".

Answer (score 3):

I think, this site is for shop owners, agency owners, etc. therefore they can get a feeling how long something take.

An answer like take 3-5 days is something other than 3-4 weeks.

Answering estimations is always a problem. But getting a feeling is helpful

Comment: +1 Yes that was my feeling as well, since this site is more "business-friendly" in a sense to agencies and shop owners, these kinds of questions could come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

**I disagree.** Questions like this **shouldn't** be allowed.

> How long ...
>
> How much ...

The answer is subjective to the person answering the question's skill and what they have at their disposal. It isn't at all reflective of how long it would take the OP to do something - the fact they are asking the question defines that.

Thus, the answer has no validity.

#### Eg. How long does it take to install and configure SOLR

***For us***

1 minute - there's an installer built into the MageStack OS that we run. Even still, we've installed it over 100+ times; so it takes mere minutes to install and configure.

***For you***

1. What OS are you using
2. How many cores/instances do you need to run (staging/development/live)
3. What level of access do you have to the machine (root/non-priv)
4. Is there an available binary in your OS repo or do you need to compile from source
5. Are you looking to tailor to any specific requirements (language, attribute weighting etc.)
6. Are you running a single machine, or multi-machine configuration

etc.

Also include the fact there will be a cycle of rinse-wash-repeat as further information is extracted by means of answer editing, or comment addition. All to derive an answer which is ultimately useless to others.

#### It is a shopping question and thus off-topic

Server fault frowns upon shopping/consultancy type questions - why should it be any different here?

#### If the question was more specific

> How can I ...

Then it becomes something worthwhile to other readers and users - and far more suitable to the Q&A format of the website.

Comment: +1.  Thanks this helps to articulate some of the underlying assumptions that I had.  Gonna chew on it for a bit but I think I'll give this the answer :)

Comment: Updated the question with some thoughts.  :)