# Should those profiting from answers be allowed to ask questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm struggling to find the comparative question from Meta Server Fault - but I believe there is a ruling down a similar vein as to this.

Taking [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/412/randomly-wrong-store-view-in-email) as an example. It begins with

> in a client's website

Which immediately implies the person in question is looking to profit from the answer someone else takes the time to provide.

I understand that the omission of this comment wouldn't somehow make it any more likely the OP wouldn't profit. But its presence may make people either reluctant to answer; or provide answers of low quality.

As a business, we love to contribute to the community and are big participants on SE sites. But personally, I take offence to answering a question for them (for free) knowing that they'll be charging someone else for the same information.

I'm not sure exactly what the best solution is, whether the question is edited to suit - or deleted outright.

Comment: Wouldn't most questions on this site be considered the same thing? Most of us work with Magento for a living, on client sites, so naturally when we are asking a question 80% of the time it has emerged from working on sites that we or our companies are charging for?

Comment: I tend to agree with @Glo. Also consider the fact that simply using a technique or a code snippet provided by someone else completely neglects every other facet of that developer-client relationship like sales, support, client acquisition, infrastructure, etc. Yes, you might feel a little cheated by providing something, for free, to someone who is charging for their service... but that service involves so much more than simply a code-snippet found online.